# Finding the absolute extrema for a multivariable function with bounds

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the following question:

> Find the absolute extrema for the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-4xy$ bounded by $y=x$, $y=-3$, and $x=3$.

This is my work:
[image]

I feel pretty confident in my work (although that confidence might be completely misplaced :) ) but I'm not understanding how these points are in the region given by the bounds. I see how they each make sense individually, but when I put it together, I don't understand the big picture. Can anyone explain that?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The equations given as conditions are lines which cut off a region of the plane. That is, they define the domain of the function. Namely the triangular region defined by $$-3\le x\le 3,\,y\le x$ and $y\ge -3.$

Comment: That is, you need to calculate the function at the boundary of the region before concluding about *absolute* extrema.

Comment: @Allawonder Meaning something more than I did here?

Comment: Yes. Consider also the vertices of the domain.